# NodeJS multi site web scrape

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am learning NodeJS and trying to scrape a fan wikia to get names of characters and store them in a json file. I have an array of character names and I want to loop through them and scrape each character name from each url in the array. The issue I am running into is:

```
throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
```

Here is my source code at the moment:

```
var express = require('express');
var fs      = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var app     = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){

  var bosses = ["Boss1","Boss2"];
  for (boss in bosses) {



    url = 'http://wikiasiteexample.com/' + bosses[boss];

    request(url, function (error, response, html) {
      if (!error) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        var title;
        var json = { title: "" };

        $('.page-header__title').filter(function () {
          var data = $(this);
          title = data.text();
          json.title = title;
        })
      }


      fs.writeFile('output.json', JSON.stringify(json, null, 4),  {'flag':'a'},  function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
        }
    });

      res.send('Check your console!')
    })
  }  
})


app.listen('8081')
console.log('Running on port 8081');
exports = module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `res.send()` for every request you make.

Your HTTP request can only have one response, so that gives an error.

You must call `res.send()` exactly once.
Promises (and `Promise.all()`) will help you do that.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I have not used promises before and will have to research more about them! I tried wrapping my request function in a promise, but have not had luck yet.