# NodeJS Web Scraping multi sites with promises output to json file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Im using nodejs to scrape multiple fan sites as a practice exercise for myself. I am able to get the data I need and want, but I am having issues writing these to my json file, as I get `[content content]` instead of my desired titles.

Previous question: [NodeJS multi site web scrape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48505533/nodejs-multi-site-web-scrape)

Here is my source code currently:

```
var express = require('express');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var app = express();
var rp = require('request-promise');
var fsp = require('fs-promise');

app.get('/', function(req, res){

  url = 'http://fansite1.com/character1';
  url1 = 'http://fansite1.com/character2';


  function parse(html) {
    var title;
    var json = { title: "" };
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    $('.page-header__title').filter(function () {
      var data = $(this);
      title = data.text();
      json.title = title;
      console.log(json.title);
    })
    return json;
  }
  var append = file => content => fsp.appendFile(file, content);
  rp(url)
  .then(parse)
  .then(append('output.json'))
  .then(() => console.log('Success'))
  .then(res.send('Check your console!'))  
  .catch(err => console.log('Error:', err));

  rp(url1)
  .then(parse)
  .then(append('output.json'))
  .then(() => console.log('Success'))
  .then(res.send('Check your console again!'))  
  .catch(err => console.log('Error:', err));
})

app.listen('8081')
console.log('Running on port 8081');
exports = module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Is `title` at `title = data.text()` a valid `JSON` value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are giving it a POJO (plain old JavaScript object), but to write it to a file, you need to convert it to a string with `JSON.stringify()`.

The easiest place to make the change looks like in your append function:

```
var append = file => content => fsp.appendFile(file, JSON.stringify(content));
```

Comment: oh DUH! I can't believe I overlooked this.

Comment: `.stringify(content, null, 2)` if you'd like beautifed output